# The content type application/json; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)

Tags: json, binding, wsdl, service-reference

I am getting this error message when trying to receive data back from a web service.

Here is my code:

```
ChannelFactory<IInterface> factory = new ChannelFactory<IInterface>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://example.net/MyService.svc/Test"));
var client = factory.CreateChannel();

MyObj x = client.Test();
```

Although I get the error, I can see the response (a JSON string) in the error message. I tried changing the Binding to `WebHttpBinding`, as well as adding an endpoint behavior of `WebHttpBehavior`, but this simply returns a null object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Initially I was correct in using WebHttpBinding, however for the endpoint behavior I needed to modify it slightly. Heres the working code:

```
ChannelFactory<IInterface> factory = new ChannelFactory<IInterface>(new WebHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://example.net/MyService.svc/Test"));

WebHttpBehavior behavior = new WebHttpBehavior()
{ 
    DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    DefaultBodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    HelpEnabled = true,
    DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
};

factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);

var client = factory.CreateChannel();

MyObj x = client.Test();
```